# horizontal grid in D3 not stretching to full length of svg

Tags: d3.js

how can I specify the width of my horizontal grid in D3?  the ticks are running horizontally and not reaching the end of the svg where the rest of my bubble chart reaches to.

thanks

Comment: You can control the ticks being shown with [`axis.ticks()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks) for example.

Comment: thanks Lars. I ended up fixing it by adjusting  .tickSize(width, 0, 0)